# Sending an image with axios to Node.js and then using it further

Tags: javascript, node.js, axios, multipartform-data

I am trying to upload an image from the front-end, `post` it with axios to back-end (node.js) and then from there `post` it again to the GroupMe image service.

The main thing is to avoid using the API token in the front-end and so I was trying to first send a request to the back-end and then send the actual API request to the GroupMe image service which expects to get FormData of an image and sends back converted image URL.

I have tried to send FormData directly to the GroupMe image service from the front-end and everything works fine. However, in order to do so, I had to store the token in the front-end, which is not a good idea I believe.

The working code below:

```
let config = {
    headers : {
        'X-Access-Token': myToken,
        'Content-Type' : 'multipart/form-data'
    }
}
let fd = new FormData()
fd.append('name', 'image')
fd.append('file', fileToUpload)

axios.post'(https://image.groupme.com/pictures', fd, config)
.then((response)=>{
    console.log(response)
})
.catch(err =>{
    console.log(err.response)
})
```

What I need to happen instead is to send the request to the back-end like so:

```
axios.post(process.env.baseUrl+'/messengerRequests/upload-file/', fd, config)
.then((response)=>{
    console.log(response)
})
.catch(err =>{
    console.log(err.response)
})
```

And now in the back-end somehow be able to get that FormData and then create another post request to the GroupMe image service as I initially did in the front-end.

```
sendMessage: async(req, res) => {
 axios.post('https://image.groupme.com/pictures', ???, config)
 .then((response)=>{
    res.send(response)
 })
 .catch(err =>{
    console.log(err.response)
 })
}
```

I do not know where it appears in the axios request. There is nothing in the `req.body` or `req.params` so I am not able to simply pass it further for the next `post`.

Is there a way somehow pass this FormData again? 
Or maybe there is a way to safely use the token in the frond-end?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, it should be relatively straightforward to post the image to GroupMe using Node.js and Express / Multer / Request. I've gone for Request rather than Axios on the backend since I'm more familiar with the API, but it's the same difference really.

**Node.js Code (index.js)**

```
const request = require("request");
const express = require("express");
const multer = require("multer");
const upload = multer();

const app = express();
const port = 3000;
const myToken = "" // Your API token goes here.

app.use(express.static("./"));

/* Here we take the image from the client and pass it on to GroupMe */
app.post("/uploadFile", upload.any(), (req, res) => {
    sendImageToGroupMe(req, res);
});

function sendImageToGroupMe(req, res) {

    const options = {
        uri: "https://image.groupme.com/pictures",
        body: req.files[0].buffer,
        method: "POST",
        headers: {
            "X-Access-Token" : myToken 
        }
    }

    request(options, (err, response, body) => {
        console.log("Request complete: Response: ", body);
        if (err) { 
            console.error("Request err: ", err);
            res.status(500).send("Upload failed: ", err.message);
        } else {
            res.status(201).send("Upload successful: GroupMe response: " + body);
        }
    });
}

app.listen(port);
```

**Client side**

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <script src="https://unpkg.com/axios/dist/axios.min.js"></script>
        <script>

            function uploadFile() {
                var fileToUpload  = document.querySelector('input[type=file]').files[0];       
                let config = {
                    headers : {
                        'Content-Type' : 'multipart/form-data'
                    }
                }

                let fd = new FormData()
                fd.append('name', 'image')
                fd.append('file', fileToUpload)

                axios.post('http://localhost:3000/uploadFile', fd, config)
                .then((response)=>{
                    console.log("Image posted successfully: ", response);
                    showOutput("Image posted successfully: " + response.data);
                })
                .catch(err =>{
                    console.error("Image post failed: ", err)
                    showOutput("Image post failed!");
                })
            }

            function showOutput(html) {
              document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = html;
            }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body style="margin:50px">
        <input type="file" onchange="uploadFile()"><br>
        <p id="output"></p>
    </body>
</html>
```

All files go in the same directory. You can go to http://localhost:3000/ to test the index.html code, this will be served by the Node.js server as a static file.

I get a response like below from the GroupMe API:

```
{
    "payload": {
        "url": "https://i.groupme.com/157x168.png.940f20356cd048c98478da2b181ee971",
        "picture_url": "https://i.groupme.com/157x168.png.940f20356cd048c98478da2b181ee971"
    }
}
```

We'll serve locally on port 3000, so to start the server:

```
node index.js
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for your answer. So you are actually saving the file in the server before sending it to GroupMe API, correct?

Comment: I'm just buffering the file in memory on the server. You can configure multer to save to disk too, if that is required.

Comment: Ah no, that is great. I was just not sure about this line:
```app.use(express.static("./"));```

Comment: Oh that's just for serving any static content, e.g. index.html.

Comment: If you are not sending this from the frontend then you will have to install `form-data` package in NodeJS. Also you may need to specify the `boundary` in `multipart/form-data`

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Express, you will need something to process the FormData. I have used [multer](https://github.com/expressjs/multer) for something similar before. I had to save the files into local storage, then resend the file with axios.